# Paypal Express Checkout Sandbox to test customer insufficient funds?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am implementing Paypal Checkout "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/quick-start/" on a SandBox account. How to test
if a customer has insufficient funds under sandbox?

Below code only checks if the user is authorized.

```js
onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
  return actions.payment.execute()
    .then(function () {
      window.alert('Payment Complete!');
    });
}
```

Thanks,